# If you buy a dlc amiibo in super smash bros (nintendo switch) will the amiibo purchase the dlc character

Tags: nintendo-switch, super-smash-bros-ultimate, amiibo

This confuses me a lot because I'm planning to buy and amiibo, but I'm wondering if that would give me the character also. Do I have to buy the dlc to use the amiibo character or does buying the amiibo give me access to the character?

Answer (score 3):

The behavior in this case is the same as it was in Smash 4. That is, it'll allow you to play against a computer player (CPU) who is playing as the DLC fighter, but you won't be able to play as the DLC fighter yourself.

Here's some old footage I was able to scrounge up. In Smash 4, Mewtwo was DLC, and you can see from the character selection screen, this person hadn't purchased Mewtwo: